# SVN: Including the directory but exclude directory contents

Tags: unix, svn

I'm using Subversion on Unix-based systems.

In my current working directory, the subdirectory `./tmp` is managed by Subversion. I would like all contents under `./tmp` to be ignored by subversion.

To phrase it another way: When a user does `svn checkout project/tmp`, I want them to have the directory `./tmp` in their directory. When that same user does `svn stat`, I want svn to ignore their temporary files under `./tmp` without affecting other directories like `./doc` and `./foo`.

```
% svn stat
?       foo/bar.tar.gz
?       tmp/foo.example.org
?       tmp/host.log
?       tmp/getscript.vba
?       doc/Manuals/Nagios
?       doc/Manuals/3ware
?       doc/Manuals/markdown
```

I know that  [global-ignores](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) can be used to ignore patterns like `global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al *.swp *old .Trash`, but can it ignore all files under a given directory? I have tried adding `/tmp/*` `tmp/*` `*/tmp/*` to global-ignores to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `svn propset svn:ignore '*' ./tmp` which will set the per-directory ignore glob in the ./tmp directory.  Be sure you quote the * or else your shell will replace it with whatever files are in the folder you're in now.

Comment: This works great. Is this possible to set in `~/.subversion/config`?

Comment: Not that I can figure out, since this is a property of a specific directory in a specific repository.  If you want this to apply to every tmp folder in every project anywhere, it might be possible through the auto-props feature but all the documentation I have on that talks about files, not directories, and autoprops are only used on `add` and `import` commands, so they would not help on existing repositories.  On top of all that, a setting in ~/.subversion/config would only apply to you, svn:ignore applies to everyone.